# Можно ли изменить форму JButton при наведении курсора?

Tags: java

Java Swing. Например была прямоугольная кнопка, нужно сделать круглую. Можно ли перерисовать существующую прямоугольную кнопку или нужно создать две кнопки и делать их видимыми поочерёдно? Нужны любые советы.

Comment: придется реализовывать свой класс JButton

Comment: @woland, у меня есть класс для создания круглой кнопки. Мне нужно создать 2 объекта и менять их видимость при наведении??? Вы об этом?

Comment: Я имел ввиду что-то типа того: добавляем обработчик события движения мыши, в котором перерисовываем кнопку круглой; когда курсор за пределами кнопки - перерисовываем обратно.

Comment: @woland, а можно что-нибудь подробнее  том как именно осуществляется это перерисование. Я вот этого и понять то не могу. Может где пример какой есть. Можно описать последовательность действий(алгоритм).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423950/java-rounded-swing-jbutton